# AngularJS does not refresh when a checkbox is updated with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, garlicjs

I have an HTML page using AngularJS.

This is basically a listing which can be filtered by clicking on some checkboxes.

I want to use jQuery 'garlic' plugin to memorize checkboxes states.

The plugin is working well, except that AngularJS "does not see" the checkbox states: the listing is not filtered according to checkboxes states. Even without using 'garlic' I have the same problem, I if do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-checkbox-tracked-by-angular).attr('checked',true_or_false).change();
});
```

The checkbox itself is visually updated but AngularJS is not triggered.

The only thing that worked to trigger AngularJS is to use click event :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-checkbox-tracked-by-angular).trigger("click");
});
```

AngularJS is updating the listing, but the click event is also switching the checkbox to the opposite state, and I do not want that.

Is there a way to tell Angular to refresh when a angular-tracked checkbox is updated outside angular ?

Note: I also tried :

```
$scope.$apply();
```

But $scope is undefined despite my code is after angular loading. 
I have AngularJS V1.2.1. How can I get access to $scope ?

Comment: use `$scope.$apply(function() { ...  here you call jquery to do some actions... });` , it tells angular that you will do something and that he has to do some check after the function is called

Comment: It is better to incorporate the jQuery function into the AngularJS framework and manupulate the scope model.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to tell Angular to refresh when a angular-tracked
>   checkbox is updated outside angular ?

Yes, there is something called "dirty checking" which can help you in order to achieve this (See [scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)).

In order to tell AngularJS to do dirty checking you can do `$scope.$apply();`. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-checkbox-tracked-by-angular').attr('checked',true_or_false).change();

    // do dirty checking!
    // wrap it inside $timeout in order to avoid Action Already In Progress
    // you can laverage this in your app. Maybe it's not necessary,
    // but that depends on your entire app architecture and interaction
    // between all angularjs elements (controllers, directives, etc)
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

If, for any reason, you could not do this, maybe, you could use as a workaround to trigger the `click` event twice. It is not the best solution and surely not the cleanest one, but it will do the job. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-checkbox-tracked-by-angular).trigger("click").trigger("click");
});
```

**Caution**:

If you mix AngularJS and jQuery for DOM manipulation directly, do it cautiously, it can become a mess. In order to get some more background about why, read ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/5640649).

**Additional readings**:

- [$rootScope.Scope#$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)
- [Action Already In Progress](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog)
- [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: It would be so much better and native to use [ngAttr](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) or just `ngModel` instead of that jQuery mess

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree with you. I just answered the specific question. I've been struggling in that mess in some occasions too (in a **very** similar situation where the OP is, while maintaining legacy code) and this is useful. That said, I should add that to the post. Thanks for your feedback! I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: I do not have access to $scope nor $timeout it is undefined despite my code is after angular loading. I have AngularJS V1.2.1. How can I get access to these objects ?

Comment: @Eric you could try to "inject" them doing something like this https://gist.github.com/umidjons/1fb8ae674df4c71f85cf

Comment: Does not work. I also tried angular.element("#my-checkbox-tracked-by-angular").scope().$apply(); but does not work too.